# ajustar fila al tamaño del texto JTable Java

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, java-ee, jtable

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de escritorio donde ejecuto consultas de una base de datos MySQL y muestro los datos en un JTable (JAVA). En un principio el texto mostrado se cortaba según el ancho de la tabla, situación que pude resolver con el código que está disponible en esta página: https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/

Sin embargo, en las consultas hay textos muy largos y al momento de ejecutar las consultas, las filas del JTable, son tan largas como el texto. He buscado en muchos foros la solución. Algunos mencionan que incluya un área de texto en cada columna, pero esa solución es más apropiada para datos estáticos o bien, calendarios. **Quisiera saber si es posible mostrar datos en un JTable de modo que la tabla se ajuste al texto**, es decir, que en lugar de mostrar una fila muy grande, muestre una fila con múltiples líneas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Es posible ajustar el texto en un JTable?**

El código que uso para la consulta el siguiente: (omití el código para mostrar todo el texto en una sola fila, en vista que es casi exactamente igual al de la página que mencione anteriormente: https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/ )

```
private ResultSet         resultadoConsulta;
private PreparedStatement consultarDatos;    
private PreparedStatement insertarDatos; 
private final Conexion    conectarBasdeDatos; 
private DefaultTableModel tituloResultadoBusqueda;

private DefaultTableModel setTitulosTabla(){
        tituloResultadoBusqueda = new DefaultTableModel();
        tituloResultadoBusqueda.addColumn("Nombre");
        tituloResultadoBusqueda.addColumn("Fecha");
        tituloResultadoBusqueda.addColumn("Información");
        return tituloResultadoBusqueda;       

    }        


public DefaultTableModel getResultado(int criterio){                    
            String sqlBusqueda = "CALL CRITERIO('" + criterio +"')";                                 
    try {
            setTitulosTabla();
            consultarDatos = conectarBasdeDatos.getConnection().prepareStatement(sqlBusqueda);
            resultadoConsulta=consultarDatos.executeQuery();           
            Object[] fila = new Object[3]; 
            while (resultadoConsulta.next()){
            fila[0]= resultadoConsulta.getString(1);
            fila[1]= resultadoConsulta.getString(2);
            fila[2]= resultadoConsulta.getString(3);          
            tituloResultadoBusqueda.addRow(fila);        
        } 
   } catch (SQLException e) { 
         System.out.println ("Error al listar los datos : " + e.getMessage());    
        } 
    return tituloResultadoBusqueda;    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se trata de construir un **CellRenderer** como el siguiente:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TextAreaRenderer extends JTextArea
    implements TableCellRenderer {

  public TextAreaRenderer() {
    setLineWrap(true);
    setWrapStyleWord(true);
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable,
      Object obj, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
      int column) {
    setText((String)obj);
    return this;
  }
}
```

**e incorporarlo a tu tabla** tal y como muestra el siguiente ejemplo:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class TextAreaRendererTest extends JFrame {
  // The table has 10 rows and 3 columns
  private final JTable table = new JTable(10, 3);

  public TextAreaRendererTest() {
    // We use our cell renderer for the third column
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(
      new TextAreaRenderer());
    // We hard-code the height of rows 0 and 5 to be 100
    table.setRowHeight(0, 100);
    table.setRowHeight(5, 100);
    // We put the table into a scrollpane and into a frame
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    // We then set a few of the cells to our long example text
    String test = "The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox";
    table.getModel().setValueAt(test, 0, 0);
    table.getModel().setValueAt(test, 0, 1);
    table.getModel().setValueAt(test, 0, 2);
    table.getModel().setValueAt(test, 4, 0);
    table.getModel().setValueAt(test, 4, 1);
    table.getModel().setValueAt(test, 4, 2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    TextAreaRendererTest test = new TextAreaRendererTest();
    test.setSize(600, 600);
    test.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    test.show();
  }
}
```

fuente: javaspecialists.eu https://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue045.html

Comment: Muchas gracias David, por  tomarte el tiempo en responder a mi pregunta. Tu orientación me fue de gran ayuda.